# Which JDBC jar should I use with java 1.5.0_16 and SQL server 2005

Tags: java, sql-server-2005

What Jdbc jar should I use :

`jdbc.jar` or `jbdc4.jar`

Comment: Are you sure you can't upgrade any of this?

Answer (score 2):

Check out: https://www.dbvis.com/doc/microsoft-sql-server-database-drivers/

It looks like neither.  You should be using the sqljdbc4.jar supplied by MS, or the jtds driver from sourceforge.

The SQL Server 2005 install should've shipped with a jdbc driver.  Check the bin folder?

Good luck!

Comment: The Microsoft drivers where sh!t (some might say intentionally hobbled) last time I used them, which is a few years back now, however at the time jTDS was definitely the one to go for

Comment: Agreed... I had the same experience.  Microsoft FTW!

Comment: Yes I mean sqljdbc. 
But sqljdbc4.jar is used with java 1.6 or later isn't it?

Comment: It's hard to go back in time when it comes to MS documentation.  Their current docs are bad enough. The best I can tell you would be to try it out.  You know... test.

Comment: According to jtds documentation at http://jtds.sourceforge.net/features.html, the jtds driver version 1.2 is compatible all the way back to Java 1.3.  I think you'll be okay.